# How get value in class using diferent href and same class name using c#

Tags: c#, class, href

I'm trying to programatically get value in HTML code of a site.
example:

€45,792.83
€3,251.15

How do i get value in "cmc-link" class of second line?

Code:

```
HtmlElement EtheriumCoin = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("cmc-link");
 textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(EtheriumCoin.InnerText);
```

Comment: Solution you pointed out dosent work because on page there are many classes with "cmc-link"

Comment: I'm trying to programatically get value in HTML code of a site. 
example: 
<td><div class="price___3rj7O "><a href="/currencies/bitcoin/markets/" class="cmc-link">€45,792.83</a></div></td>
<td><div class="price___3rj7O rise___39rPH"><a href="/currencies/ethereum/markets/" class="cmc-link">€3,251.15</a></div></td>

Comment: Its not duplicate question. Can you re-open please.